# How to setup greeting text or get_started in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I am trying to develop a bot for FB Messenger and I'm always getting stuck with their documentation. Currently, I tried to add a Greeting Text and a Get_Started button in JavaScript, so I will be able to modify it easily. It seems like most of their documentation is in PHP or they just telling you to add it by sending a POST request using CURL, which worked for me, but again, it's not so modular.
I can't find proper documentation in JavaScript. and the only one is this:
https://www.techiediaries.com/build-messenger-bot-nodejs/
But I can't find the place where you actually call the greeting or get started functions.
there is also this https://github.com/fbsamples/original-coast-clothing
but I still can't find where they trigger the Greetings and the Get_Started postbacks. Only the json file where they store it /locales/en_US.json "profile".

My code currently has

```
// Accepts POST requests at /webhook endpoint
app.post('/webhook', (req, res) => {  

  // Parse the request body from the POST
  let body = req.body;

  // Check the webhook event is from a Page subscription
  if (body.object === 'page') {

    // Iterate over each entry - there may be multiple if batched
    body.entry.forEach(function(entry) {

      // Get the webhook event. entry.messaging is an array, but 
      // will only ever contain one event, so we get index 0
      let webhook_event = entry.messaging[0];
      console.log(webhook_event);

      // Get the sender PSID
      let sender_psid = webhook_event.sender.id;
      console.log('Sender PSID: ' + sender_psid);

      // Check if the event is a message or postback and
      // pass the event to the appropriate handler function
      if (webhook_event.message) {
        handleMessage(sender_psid, webhook_event.message);        
      } else if (webhook_event.postback) {
        handlePostback(sender_psid, webhook_event.postback);
      }

    });

    // Return a '200 OK' response to all events
    res.status(200).send('EVENT_RECEIVED');

  } else {
    // Return a '404 Not Found' if event is not from a page subscription
    res.sendStatus(404);
  }

});

function setupGreetingText(res){
var messageData = {
    "greeting":[
        {
        "locale":"default",
        "text":"Greeting text for default local !"
        }, {
        "locale":"en_US",
        "text":"Greeting text for en_US local !"
        }
    ]};
request({
    "uri": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages",
    "qs": { "access_token": process.env.PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN },
    "method": 'POST',
    "headers": {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    "form": messageData
},
function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        // Print out the response body
        res.send(body);

    } else { 
        // TODO: Handle errors
        res.send(body);
    }
});

}
```

but I still dont know how to trigger it.

Answer (score 1):

Examples on the documentation look like this. This is how you break it down. Final result can be found below.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "get_started": {"payload": "<postback_payload>"}
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile?access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>"
```

1. Third word is the type of request you'll send and should be defined inside the method property.
2. Between the curly braces, is how the content inside the `json` property should be formatted.
3. The link on the last line is the link you should provide to the `uri` property minus the query part `?access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>`

   1. SendAPI's uri is https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/me/messages (you're using this)
   2. MessengerProfileAPI's uri is https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile (use this instead)

In the end, your request function should look something like this:

```
request(
    {
      "uri": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile",
      "qs": { "access_token": process.env.PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN },
      "method": "POST",
      "json": {
        "get_started": {"payload": "start"}
      },
    }, 
    (err) => {
      if (!err) {
        console.log('request sent!');
      } else {
        console.error("Unable to send message:" + err);
      }
    }
  );
```

Even though its been almost 3 months since this question has been asked. I hope this will still come useful.

Was struggling and frustrated as you trying to implement the examples on facebook for developers documentation but I finally got to understand it after some looking and observation at other developers webhook on github.